# PHP - HTML special characters don't change in text input

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I using the PFBC (PHP form builder class ([PFBC](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/index.php))) to create a TextBox element in page;

But in string with special character's he not change to normal characters:

ex: `$razao = "livia&#39;s baby"`

```
    $form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("Razão Social:", "data[RAZAO_SOCIAL]", array(
    "value" => htmlspecialchars_decode($razao, ENT_NOQUOTES) ,
    "required" => true
)));
```

He print:

[click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHgEa.png)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENT_NOQUOTES` tells the `htmlspecialchars_decode` to not decode single or double quotes. Use `ENT_QUOTES`.

> Will convert both double and single quotes.

vs.

> Will leave both double and single quotes unconverted.

-http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($razao, ENT_QUOTES)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ZSH7G

Be careful with this though, depending on `$razao`'s value you might open yourself to XSS injections.

Comment: thanks, works \o; "Be careful with this though, depending on $razao's value you might open yourself to XSS injections." i'm get this value from the database, the Propel framework saving with this character =p

Comment: Propel is just an ORM. It shouldn't be changing your content. Maybe the `addElement` protects you though.

Comment: is possible to =d